# Harddisk with >10k bad sectors

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, hard-drive-failure

My computer has two drive : SSD for C drive ,HDD for D drive
My Windows OS is installed in C drive

Recently ,when I click the folders ,the File Manager always hangs. I cant even turn off the computer (with deadloop). Cant turn on the computer as well ,it goes windows diskcheck (I spent >48 hrs on it and can't finish ).

Then I use HDD-SCAN to scan my HD(d drive) .It shows more than 5k bad sectors.

What should I do now ? Just reinstall the OS ? Buy a new HDD?Any HD repairing software ?

(noted that I cannot drag and drop to backup the file in d drive now )

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> HDD-SCAN to scan my HD(d drive) .It shows more than 5k bad sectors.

This drive is in such bad shape (many errors) that you should not use it. It will not be reliable.

So you should recover any data you can (put on an external USB drive).  If you cannot do this because of the errors, you need to consider using a local data recovery agency to see if they can recover the data.

Then replace the drive.

Consider using a large, good quality SSD for replacement as that will likely work better.

Comment: But I cant drag the file to USB Drive right now

Comment: That is because of all the errors on the drive. You may have to take the drive to a local recovery company, but with all the errors, that may not work either

Comment: @evabb - The fact you cannot transfer a file is another indication the drive has so many bad sectors, it will only continue to happen, as data is moved around the disk.  The file you can't move is likely gone unless you are willing to pay for data recovery with specialized tools.  As the number of bad sectors continue to increase, the number of I/O errors will continue, eventually the drive will be inaccessible due to those errors.

Comment: @Ramhound So , I just let go with the D drive data , replace of a new one and ,reinstall the system ? What is the reason of getting so many bad sectors?

Comment: The existing drive may have been an economy drive or failed early - this happens as well.

Comment: Then should I reinstall the system afterward?

Comment: If your system is on the SSD drive (your C: drive) you may not need to reinstall the operating system (that depends where you installed the OS). If you put apps on the HDD, these would have to be reinstalled.

Comment: @evabb - The drive is starting to fail.  You can either pay to recover the data off the drive since it's likely at least partially a mechanical problem or throw the drive in the trash.  **If the drive shouldn't be use to hold any data at all.**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there seems to be a bug in HDDScan 4.1. In reality, you probably have many fewer bad sectors which you could easily remap with WD Data Lifeguard Diagnostics, but HDDScan marks all sectors after the bad one as bad. I strongly discourage from using this particular version (4.1). Instead, use version 3.3 or WD Data Lifeguard Diagnostics or even simple chkdsk.